# Trying to do a div loop

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm trying to do a `foreach` showing database information. I want to do a loop of `div`s with this information.

One example: if I have 4 `registers` on database I will have 4 different `div`s. How can I do that?

This is my blade file:

```html
@extends('layouts.app_cad_livros')

@section('content')
    <div class="textocs">
        <br>
        <h3>LIVROS</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card_livro">
        @foreach($livro as $mostra)
            {{$mostra->users_id}}
            TÍTULO   {{$mostra->namel}}<br>
            AUTOR {{$mostra->autor}}<br>
            EDITORA {{$mostra->editora}}<br>
            CATEGORIA {{$mostra->categoria}}<br>
            CLASSIFICAÇÃO {{$mostra->classificação}}<br>
            DESCRIÇÃO {{$mostra->descricao}}<br>
            CAPA {{$mostra->image}}<br>
            <a href="{{ url('/register')}}">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
            </a>
            <br>
            <td>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What is actually doing as it should be displaying the amount you want. Also, you have an HTML error, you have a lonely `<td>` but you are not inside a `table` nor you are closing the `<td>` and it has no information inside it. Show us your current result so we can understand what is wrong, and also show us your controller so we can see what you are sending to your view.

Comment: if you want 4 divs then add the foreach before of the <div> tag

Answer (score 0):

Just change the @foreach loop. Try this:

```
@extends('layouts.app_cad_livros')

@section('content')
    <div class="textocs">
        <br>
        <h3>LIVROS</h3>
    </div>

    @foreach($livro as $mostra)
    <div class="card_livro">
            {{$mostra->users_id}}
            TÍTULO   {{$mostra->namel}}<br>
            AUTOR {{$mostra->autor}}<br>
            EDITORA {{$mostra->editora}}<br>
            CATEGORIA {{$mostra->categoria}}<br>
            CLASSIFICAÇÃO {{$mostra->classificação}}<br>
            DESCRIÇÃO {{$mostra->descricao}}<br>
            CAPA {{$mostra->image}}<br>
            <a href="{{ url('/register')}}">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
            </a>
    </div>
    @endforeach

@endsection
```

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work. When I try on this way appears only one div with one register but I have four on database.

Comment: Before sending the data to the view, check your variable with the method dd($livro) so you can see the actual ammount of records.